# How to access shared folder in the windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created windows service using csharp in that i am accessing shared folders which is from other system,
But i am facing error while accessing the folders,
How to resolve this problem.

Please suggest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run the service under an account that has permissions to access that network resource.

[image]

Comment: Plus, you need to add the network resource to the correct "Zone" (in the Intranet Settings dialog", usually I use "Local Intranet") and give the correct CASPOL permissions to that Zone.

Comment: As u mentioned i tried and now I Have given permission in local security settings by adding that account in log on as a service and it is working fine, and same account i given permission for the shared folder now it is able to read that files.